# Localhost redirected too many times to send emails in Django

Tags: django, email, redirect

I am trying to view the contact page where users can send emails. However, when I URL to "/contact" it shows an "error: localhost has redirected me many times." I cleared my cookies several times. It worked before and now this error persists. Can someone please check if there's any coding error I must have made? I appreciate your thorough feedback!

views.py

```
ef contact(request):
    if request.method!='POST':
        return redirect('/contact')
    error=False
    if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(request.POST['from_email']):
        messages.error(request, "Please enter proper email")
        error=True
    if len(request.POST['message'])<2:
        messages.error(request, "Please enter message")
        error=True    
    else:
        message=request.POST.get('message')
        from_email=request.POST.get('from_email')

        email = EmailMessage(
            subject='Contact Form',
            body=message,
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            to=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
            reply_to=[from_email]
        )
        email.send(fail_silently=False)

        messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message! We will reply soon.")
    return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
```

contact.html

```
 <h1 class=text-center>Contact</h1>
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-success p-2 pb-3">
                    <a class="close font-weight-normal initialism" data-dismiss="alert" href="#"><samp>×</samp></a> 
                        {{message}}
                </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            <form action="/contact" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="from_email" placeholder="Please enter e-mail" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Please enter message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="/contact" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be like this

```py
def contact(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        error=False
        if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(request.POST['from_email']):
            messages.error(request, "Please enter proper email")
            error=True
        if len(request.POST['message'])<2:
            messages.error(request, "Please enter message")
            error=True    
        else:
            message=request.POST.get('message')
            from_email=request.POST.get('from_email')

            email = EmailMessage(
                subject='Contact Form',
                body=message,
                from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                to=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
                reply_to=[from_email]
            )
            email.send(fail_silently=False)

            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message! We will reply soon.")
    return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error in regards to the redirect is with your first `if` statement. When you navigate to /contact, you're performing a GET request and since it isn't POST, it's redirecting over and over again. Once that's resolved, you'll run into another issue when going to /contact because you're not catching GET requests and displaying your contact form. I'd take a look at the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view) as an example on how to handle GET and POST requests for your form.

Comment: @junsenbrnr--thank you for the heads up. I edited my code: `def contact(request):
    message=request.POST.get('message')
    from_email=request.POST.get('from_email')

    email = EmailMessage(
        subject='Contact Form',
        body=message,
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        to=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
        reply_to=[from_email]
    )
    email.send(fail_silently=False)
    messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message! We will reply soon.")
    return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
`

Comment: Though, my only concern is how do I make the success message appear after the user submits the form? Thanks for your help!